# Rails 4 - undefined method 'attributes' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a many-to-many relationship between Users and Documents. Users can invite other users to collaborate on their documents by entering their email. The application will look up a user by email and set the user_id in DocumentUser. If a user is not found, I am getting this error: Rails 4 - undefined method 'attributes' for nil:NilClass. This error occurs in DocumentUsersControlller.create. How can I prevent this error using best practices? Also, why doesn't the presence validator prevent this error?

Here are the relevant controllers and models:

```
class DocumentUsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @document = Document.find_by link_key: params[:document_id]
    @document_user = @document.document_users.build
  end

def create

  @document = Document.find_by link_key: params[:document_id]
  @document_user = @document.document_users.build(document_user_params)
  user = User.find_by email: params[:document_user][:email]  
  @document_user.user = user if user

  respond_to do |format|
      if @document_user.save  #error occurs here if user is Nil
          format.html { redirect_to @document, notice: 'User Invitation was sent.'}
          format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @document_user }
      else
          format.html { render action: 'new' }
          format.json { render json: @document_user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end

  end
end

def destroy
end

private

def document_user_params
    params.require(:document_user).permit(:email, :admin, :editor, :viewer)
end

end


class DocumentUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  include KeyCreator

  belongs_to :document
  belongs_to :user
  before_create :before_create

    attr_accessor :email

    validates :user, uniqueness: { message: "has already been invited" }
    validates :user, presence: true
    validate :email_matches_user

    def to_param
        "#{invite_key}".parameterize
    end

 private

    def before_create
        now = DateTime.now      
        self.added_date = now
        self.modified_date = now
        self.invite_key = create_key
        self.api_key = create_key
    end

   def email_matches_user
       unless User.exists? email: email 
           errors.add(:email, "does not match any existing user")
       end
   end

end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include KeyCreator

    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :document_users
has_many :documents, :through => :document_users
before_create :before_create

private

    def before_create
        self.api_key = create_key
    end

end


class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
     include KeyCreator

has_many :document_users, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, :through => :document_users
    before_create :before_create

    def self.created_by(user)
        Document.joins(:document_users).where(:document_users => {:user => user, :creator => true}).order(:name)
    end

    def self.guest_in(user)
        Document.joins(:document_users).where(:document_users => {:user => user, :creator => false}).order(:name)
    end

    def to_param
        "#{link_key}".parameterize
    end

private

    def before_create
        now = DateTime.now
        self.content = nil
        self.created_date = now
       self.modified_date = now
       self.deleted_date = nil
       self.api_key = create_key
       self.link_key = create_key
    end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `email_matches_user`. It should be matching
`email:` with `self.email`:

```
def email_matches_user
   unless User.exists? email: self.email 
       errors.add(:email, "does not match any existing user")
   end
end
```